# OpenMPI MPI_Comm_spawn() giving unreachable errors

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I've got a master and worker system, where the master uses OpenMPI to spawn and communicate with its workers. I've used versions 4.0.4 and 3.1.6, both are giving similar errors.

master.cxx

```
#include <mpi.h>

void doStuff() {
    // does stuff
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int NUM_JOBS = 10; 

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    char * args[] = {"Arg1","Arg2",NULL,};

    MPI_Info mpi_info;
    MPI_Info_create(&mpi_info);
    MPI_Info_set(mpi_info, "add-hostfile", "nodefile");

    MPI_Comm child_comm;
    MPI_Comm_spawn("worker", args, NUM_JOBS, mpi_info, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &child_comm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);

    doStuff();

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

worker.cxx

```
#include <mpi.h>

void doStuff() {
    // does stuff
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    doStuff();
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Both are compiled via cmake. I have 101 cores available to me, for 1 master and up to 100 workers, with 24 cores per node. For the first run, I'm just doing workers to prove that it can run. I had to add in some infiniband parameters

run1.sh

```
export OMPI_MCA_btl_openib_allow_ib=1
export OMPI_MCA_btl_openib_if_include="mlx4_0:1"
mpirun -n 101 --mca btl openib,self --hostfile nodefile worker
```

Now, I try to run the workers using the master. Note that the code as written above spawns 10 workers, so the 11 total procs can fit on one 24-core node.

run2.sh

```
export OMPI_MCA_btl_openib_allow_ib=1
export OMPI_MCA_btl_openib_if_include="mlx4_0:1"
mpirun -n 1 --mca btl openib,self --hostfile nodefile master
```

That works fine. So I up master.cxx NUM_JOBS=100 and repeat the run using run2.sh

This time, I get an MPI error and the job fails

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
At least one pair of MPI processes are unable to reach each other for
MPI communications. This means that no Open MPI device has indicated
that it can be used to communicate between these processes. This is
an error; Open MPI requires that all MPI processes be able to reach
each other. This error can sometimes be the result of forgetting to
specify the "self" BTL.

   Process 1 ([[53646,2],88]) is on host: mymachine04
   Process 2 ([[53636,1],0]) is on host: unnknown1
   BTLs attempted: self openib

Your MPI job is now going to abort; sorry.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[mymachine04:22480] [[53646,2],88] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Unreachable in file dpm/dpm.c at line 493
```

That last line is repeated 77 total times. Presumably uncoincidentally, 101 procs - 24 procs per node = 77. The hostfile is just 101 lines of hostnames, and I get the same error whether I supply it or not. Interestingly, if I remove the first line of the hostfile before spawning my workers, on the grounds that that slot is already used by the master, I get an error about running out of slots. Any idea what I'm doing wrong, how I can get all of my processes to reach each other?

Comment: This sounds like a configuration problem, but just to be sure, can you query `MPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE` to see if you MPI actually thinks it can spawn? Also, try adding the option `-usize 100`.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, Victor. The universe size is 101 as expected, so I don't think that's the issue. The error message makes it sound like loopback isn't working across nodes. It's odd, since it works fine if I do 101 procs directly through mpirun, and the error message says it's attempting the self and openib BTLs.